# How can I extend/configure other plone addons preferences Configlets?

Tags: interface, plone, adapter, add-on

I have a third-party addon installed and now I have to extend this Configlet with a boolean Field, how can I do this?

Further I have to use results of a function from this addon?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to grep for AddForm in the add-on and take a look at http://kayeva.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/using-z3cform-for-our-forms-in-plone/ from some starting point.

Comment: This is almost nonsensical, can you tell us what add-on and what exactly you want to do with it? I don't understand "use results of a function".

Comment: Sorry, I will try a more detailed question.

This installed third-party Add-on (collective.simplesocial) uses a ControlPanelForm to modify his settings and I want to add (in this c.simplesocial configlet) a Boolean Field, which enables my own tool to receive data from collective.simplesocial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either try

1) Override form via a custom layer registered by your add-on and create new Form class, extending the orignal, which has the same name, but is registered against this layer. Thus, the form class will come from your add-on when your add-on and it's browserlayer is installed.

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views/layers.html

Layers are view-specific, so it is the view you are trying to override. Depending on the orignal c.simplesocial architecture it is not sure what kind of view - form relationship is in place.

2) monkey-patch the orignal form class

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/misc/monkeypatch.html